# Persuading management that refactoring code is a good idea

Tags: management, refactoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best supporting argument for refactoring](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21538/best-supporting-argument-for-refactoring)

Has anyone got any tips for persuading management that refactoring code is a good idea ?  I was asked something like

> "After this refactoring, will I have a better product ?  How does time spent on this benefit the company?"

Or something along those lines.  I can see why management asked it but my response was not fantastic.  I said something about how a well designed piece of software will mean that adding new features in the future will be quicker and easier.

Does anyone else have any tips ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother.

Rather than selling refactoring as a stand alone feature combine refactoring into your estimates for implementing fixes/ new features when it makes sense to do so, generally speaking the business need not and does not want to know exactly how you plan on implementing a feature, just that it gets done.

Comment: redesign however is different, you will need management by in then

Comment: I basically agree, but unfortunately it is not always that simple :-( If you have a large heap of legacy spaghetti code, small scale refactoring to keep quality at its current level is not enough. You need a lot of extra refactoring time on top of "normal" development to visibly improve things. And a decision to spend so significant a portion of project time on refactoring should not be made by you, the developer alone (unless management is completely unreasonable - in which case it is probably better for you to look for a new workplace anyway).

Comment: @PéterTörök yes its arguable you are then straying from refactoring into redesign, so you'd probably approach this by trying to show a cost saving of the course of 1 or more development cycles rather than for an individual change, and yes it would need management by in.